# Inserting rows in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, insert, row, vba

does anyone know how to insert 4 rows after each row, from row 2 to row 5? Of course using Excel VBA. I attach a picture to explain it better.

Any hints will be really appreciated. 
Regards!

[image]

Comment: Why dont you record a macro and perform the actions. Then you can check the macro ouput in vb mode?

Comment: there are only 3 spaces between Nuevo Leon and Coahuila.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below code

```
Sub InsertRow()


    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastRow To 3 Step -1
        Cells(i, 1).Resize(4).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recorded a Macro inserting a row. The code that came out was this.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Rows("2:5").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```